# Django QuerySets on PostgreSQL contain duplicate objects

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is Django 1.4.2 running on OSX, with a PostgreSQL database.

Here's my model:

```
class RideRequest(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="ride_requests", symmetrical=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

In all my filter calls for this model, I get all objects twice.

```
[10]: queryset = RideRequest.objects.filter(id=8)
[11]: for q in queryset: print q.id
8
8
```

I just looked into the database, and every entry is only present once. Any ideas why this would happen? I can't easily switch to SQLite because of certain DB constraints.

Edit: Here's the raw SQL query output of `RideRequest.objects.filter(id=8).query`. It too returns two rows instead of the expected one. Could it be because of the excessive JOINing that is going on?

```
SELECT "rides_riderequest"."id", "rides_riderequest"."ride_id", 
…
FROM "rides_riderequest" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "rides_riderequest_ride_request_stations" 
ON ("rides_riderequest"."id" = "rides_riderequest_ride_request_stations"."riderequest_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "rides_riderequeststation" 
ON ("rides_riderequest_ride_request_stations"."riderequeststation_id" = 
"rides_riderequeststation"."id") WHERE "rides_riderequest"."id" = 8  
ORDER BY "rides_riderequeststation"."departure_time_min" DESC;
```

Comment: You could maybe use this to only select each record once: RideRequest.objects.filter(id=8).distinct()

Comment: You're right, I could, and that's my workaround right now. I'm more interested in the actual reason this bug pops up.

Comment: You can see the SQL query: print RideRequest.objects.filter(id=8).query It's possible that with this you can see something

Comment: Good Idea. The query seems legit, but running the query without the DISTINCT keyword in in the postgre console still gives me 2 lines instead of one.

Comment: All of your joins are on a single column. Shouldn't at least one of them be a join on two columns?

Comment: Is there only one record in the actual database table with id=8? What happens when you call  RideRequest.objects.get(id=8) ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that in model Meta section you have set model ordered by an 'external' field (related model `'station__departure_time'`). When you write query django make joins to this 'external' field for sorting purposes.

In this case you should use `distinct()` method or clear ordering using `.order_by()`